# SSIS Data Conversion: Is it possible to convert datatype while keeping the original field name?

Tags: ssis

I would like to convert all char and text fields to Unicode in the extract phase of my ETL data flow.

Convert Datatype transformation is the obvious widget to do the job, but I cannot find a way to assign the original field name to the new field with the converted data type.

Is it possible to change data type while keeping the field name?

[SQL Server Data Tools   16.0.62003.05170]

Comment: Indeed I was in the wrong in suggesting to use *Derived Column* to solve this as it forces to keep the data type in case you want to keep the source field name. Depending on the source component you use, you could try to simply set the external field type to `DT_WSTR` to force implicit conversion right at the start of the Data Flow.

Comment: You are right, some source components seem to be able to do the conversion. When I tried the ADO.NET source (instead of OLE DB), I could configure the external and output fields to Unicode. But, then again, ODBC source did not keep the setting, but silently fell back to DT_STR. I am baffled! Harmonizing datatypes is the first thing I would like to do when importing data into a warehouse system, and it proves to be next to impossible!? Where is the universal "Transcode all text fields in the data flow to the encoding of your choice" transform component!!!

Comment: Did you change both the External and Output Column data type? I was baffled by that too since SSIS tries to be "helpfull" and resets the data type when you allow to auto-sync column information with the data source. A last resort would be, to either create database views or use an OleDb query for your source and do the conversion there. I guess MS tries very hard to prevent you from mixing up data types and explicitly convert. One thing that usually also helps, is to cut the pipeline to the next functoid to prevent SSIS from assuming *"But it's DT_STR in the next component!"*

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Filburt's comment on some data sources being able to handle the conversion, and the observation that ADO.NET data **source** has this capability, I turned the problem setting the other way around.

ADO.NET **destinations** can also handle the data type transformation implicitly. So, I don't worry about the encodings within the extract data flow, but let the ADO.NET destination handle the transcoding when writing the extracted data to the staging table using Unicode character types.

This way I'll end up with a set of staged data with conforming character data types, and I won't have to worry about encoding issues down my dw pipeline anymore.

Not an exact solution to my question, but gets me past the acute problem. So I'll post this as a solution.